# GradientStop Color Binding on DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf

Below, I Have these Resource  i want to make binding on the third GradientStop to MyColor ,MyColor is DependencyProperty but in not working if i remove binding and put static Color "#ff000000" it is Working can some body help me???

```
 <Grid.Resources>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MyBrush" EndPoint="0, 1" StartPoint="0, 0">
                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=MyColor}" Offset="0"/>
                <!--#ff000000 -->

            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <Style x:Key="ThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate >
                            <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashCap="Round" 
                                       Stretch="Fill" Name="ThumbContnet" Fill="{StaticResource MyBrush}"></Rectangle>
                            <!---->
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
```

Regards 
Fadi AL Sayyed

Comment: What is the type of MyColor? Is it a String or a `System.Windows.Media.Color` (should be the latter)? Are there any binding errors shown in the Visual Studio output window?

Comment: yes it is System.Windows.Media.Color

Comment: How do you know you have Color in the data context?

Comment: I Set The Color ,and this is the dp.
       public static readonly DependencyProperty MyColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyColor", typeof(Color), typeof(StageToolsWindow),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((Color)Colors.Black));      
        public Color MyColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(MyColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyColorProperty, value); }
        }

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, you haven't set `DataContext` itself. Declaring a dependency property isn't enough to make bindings work. In the user control's constructor write:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty MyColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyColor", typeof(Color), typeof(StageToolsWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((Color)Colors.Black));

  public Color MyColor 
  {
    get { return (Color)GetValue(MyColorProperty); } 
    set { SetValue(MyColorProperty, value); } 
  }

  public MyControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
  }
}
```